# Watching changes to a file in Android

Tags: android

I have a file on the Android SD card and would like to monitor any changes that happen to it through any external applications via code. Is there a way of doing that? Something like 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html
has you tried FileObserver?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the system provides any sort of a callback type interface.

If you want that information I think you'd have to be check the contents of the file every so often and compare it to what you found last time. If it isn't equal then you know the file was touched by something else.

Surely this will end up being somewhat inefficient in terms of battery though I would imagine. If you must go this route I suggest as long of a duration in between checks as possible.

**EDIT:** I stand corrected. FileObserver looks like it'd be what you want. I've never run accross that one before. Props to @Grey.